# ASP.NET mvc 5 Gmail like logout from all devices and active sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way I can log out from all my active sessions on different devices and browser windows like gmail does?
any suggestions or ideas to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to keep track of all the sessions of your users. 
Save them in a database and on the moment that the user wants all his account sessions to end (like in Gmail).
You then have to delete the sessions on the server so that if you try to reinitiate the session the server does not recognise it any longer and requests the user to create a new one.

This way all the sessions are no longer vallid